# I am a business Analyst with 8+ years experience

Tags: certification

I am a business analyst with 8+ years experience and would like to get into Salesforce.  What is the certification process and which course should I concentrate on?

Comment: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=salesforce+certification

Answer (score 1):

Good luck, Chris, we've written pretty extensively on this topic:

http://www.runconsultants.com/blog/salesforce-certification-how-to-become-salesforce-certified/

There are more articles on our blog.